# Runtime error 9 when opening several workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

The goal of my code is to open several workbooks for later use.

I created a loop. The first workbook always gets opened.

At the second instance of that loop I receive

> runtime error 9

for:

```vb
file = Sheets("Start").Cells(i, 5) ' Get file name
```

In the referenced cell (Cell (2, 5), there are no entries, so I thought that the error might be connected to that. I tried to create Skip (with GoTo), which is now commented out, because I don't even know if it works.

```vb
''  Open Workbooks--------------------------------------------------------
fromPath = Sheets("Start").Cells(1, 2) ' Get path from cells on Report tab

For i = 1 To 9

    ' Make sure there is a backslash at the end of the from path
    If Right(fromPath, 1) <> "\" Then fromPath = fromPath & "\"
   
    file = Sheets("Start").Cells(i, 5) ' Get file name
    'If file = "" Then
    '    GoTo SkipTheLoop: '' If Cell is empty
    'End If

    'Make sure there is a .xlsx at the end of the file name
    If Right(file, 5) <> ".xlsx" Then file = file & ".xlsx"

    Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(fromPath & file) ' Open workbook by path and name
SkipTheLoop:
Next i
```

Comment: The file you opened in the first iteration is now the active file and the `Sheets("Start")` does not exist.  If you want to read from the original workbook you need to qualify by including the workbook in the statement.  `Workbooks("Example").Sheets....`

Comment: Or simply `file = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Cells(i, 5).Value2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Open Multiple Workbooks

**Tips**

- Use `Option Explicit` which forces you to declare all variables.
- `ThisWorkbook`, the workbook containing this code.
- Qualify objects (`wb.Worksheets...`).
- If it's a worksheet then use `Worksheet` instead of `Sheet`.
- If it's a value from a cell, then use `Value` or `Value2`.
- When using `On Error Resume Next` (*Defer error handling*), use it for one to two lines and wrap it up with `On Error Goto 0` (*Turn off error handling*).
- Note that previous is not mandatory and the code might still work without it. Until it doesn't.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim fromPath As String: fromPath = wb.Worksheets("Start").Cells(1, 2).Value
    
    Dim wkbFrom As Workbook
    Dim fName As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 9
        If Right(fromPath, 1) <> "\" Then fromPath = fromPath & "\"
        fName = wb.WorkSheets("Start").Cells(i, 5).Value
        If Right(fName, 5) <> ".xlsx" Then fName = fName & ".xlsx"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(fromPath & fName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not wkbFrom Is Nothing Then
            n = n + 1
            Set wkbFrom = Nothing
        End If
    Next i
    
    MsgBox n & " workbook(s) opened.", vbInformation, "Open Workbooks"
    
End Sub
```